# file command cannot open files when executed in subcommand

Tags: bash, unix

Why is it not possible for the file command to open files when it is running within a subcommand yet a command such as basename works perfectly fine?

```
ls
file1  file2  file3

find * -exec echo $(basename {}) \;
file1
file2
file3

find * -exec echo $(file {}) \;
file1: cannot open `file1' (No such file or directory)
file2: cannot open `file2' (No such file or directory)
file3: cannot open `file3' (No such file or directory)

find * -exec file {} \;
file1: empty
file2: empty
file3: empty
```

Comment: Because the subcommand is run **before** `find` is.

Comment: BTW, `find *` is a bad idea -- it's telling your shell to pass a list of local filenames to `find`. If that list of filenames is too long (more than ~128kb on many operating systems), that will mean `find` doesn't start at all.

Comment: What would be the best way of handling that situation, if you knew that the filenames list will be too long?

Comment: `find .`, not `find *` -- that way it's `find`'s job to look at what's in the current directory, not the shell's.

Comment: BTW, there's really no reason at all to run `echo $(something)` instead of just `something`; all it adds is bugs (if you *didn't* want it to add bugs, it would need to be `echo "$(something)"`, with the quotes; even then it can munge content containing literal backslashes -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why The Original Code Breaks

Because the subcommand is run **before** `find` is, that's completely normal and expected behavior. That is:

```
find * -exec echo $(basename {}) \;
```

...first runs...

```
basename {}
```

...which returns the string `{}`, making your command:

```
find * -exec echo {} \;
```

...which doesn't run `basename` for each of the three individual files at all.

Similarly, `find * -exec echo $(file {}) \;` first runs `file {}` and, as this returns an error message *on stdout*, substitutes that error into the commands later run by `find`.

---

#### What To Do Instead

If you want something to be run in a shell started by `find`, you need to tell `find` to start that shell:

```
# note that {} is a separate argument; this is important for security reasons.
find . -exec sh -c 'echo $(basename "$1")' _ {} \;
```

...which, by the way, is a *very* silly and needlessly inefficient way to write:

```
find . -exec basename {} \;
```

By the way, if you *do* need a shell, you can improve efficiency by passing a single shell multiple arguments:

```
find . -exec 'for arg; do basename "$arg"; done' _ {} +
```

...or you can do the loop directly in the parent process, rather than using `find -exec` at all:

```
# note that this requires a bash, not /bin/sh, shebang.
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename <&3; do
  basename "$filename"
done 3< <(find . -print0)
```

---

#### What *Not* To Do Instead

The following *looks* like it works:

```
# THIS IS EVIL; DO NOT DO THIS
find . -exec sh -c 'echo $(basename "{}")' \;
```

...however, it actually introduces seriously security vulnerabilities into your system. Why? Let's say someone made a file like so:

```
touch $'$(touch i-am-evil)\'$(touch i-am-evil)\''
```

...when your `find` command happens upon it, it then runs:

```
echo $(basename "$(touch i-am-evil)'$(touch i-am-evil)'")
```

...and `touch i-am-evil` gets run. (Replace that with any arbitrary command an attacker might want to execute on your system with the permissions of the user running `find`).

Comment: Ah, I see. I chose a very poor alternative command to file when testing the subcommand it seems. Thanks for the very in depth answer, much appreciated.

Comment: If what you want is just to get output from `file` for everything on your filesystem, consider `find . -exec file {} +` -- that's going to be more efficient than the `{} \;` approach, since it passes as many filenames as possible to each `file` invocation.

Comment: My command was to do with uploading all files in an output directory to a github release, using your answer I've found that this works well now

`find * -exec sh -c 'curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -u $2 -H "Content-Type: $(file -b --mime-type $1)" --data-binary @$1 "https://uploads.github.com/repos/testorg/dummy-deb/releases/5757575/assets?name=$(basename $1)"' _ {} $KEY \;`

Comment: so, that could be made a little more efficient like so: `find . -exec sh -c 'key=$1; shift; for arg; do curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -u "$key" -H "Content-Type: $(file -b --mime-type "$arg")" --data-binary @"$arg" "https://uploads.github.com/repos/testorg/dummy-deb/releases‌​/5757575/assets?name‌​=$(basename $1)"' _ {} +`

Comment: The other thing I really should have showcased in my answer was how to read output from `find` into the parent shell safely and do the loop there. I'll amend to demo that. (BTW, pretty much all of this is covered in [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)).